# Bootstrap Modal(Popup) is not working in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying add a new personal with Modal. Button and Popup code below. But Modal is not work, it is not opening. Where am I doing wrong? Thanks :)

```
 @model  Demo.Models.Personal
    
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
<h2>PERSONAL</h2>
<p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#personalModal">Add Personal</button>
</p>
<div class="modal fade" id="personalModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="personalModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h2 class="modal-title">New Personal</h2>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working on my end, I tried it on my plain ASP.NET MVC template. You can see the screenshot here:
[image]

- I suggest double check and inspect your site, if you have errors in
  your javascript. Make sure you are loading jQuery files and Bootstrap
  files.
- And make sure you have the proper version, in my side, I am using
  Bootstrap v3.3.7 and jQuery JavaScript Library v3.3.1. You can check
  info here:
  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#download
- Lastly, jQuery should be loaded first before Bootstrap to make it
  work.